# A little different than ordinary case of MySQL and xampp

Tags: mysql, xampp

I've been struggling with this problem for quite some time, I downloaded 
'MySQL server' and 'workbench' and installed them, later I downloaded xampp and now there is a problem that xampp comes with its own mysql and is not able to trace my already installed version, So I want to give xampp the path to my already installed MySQL. I tried installing xampp with its own mysql but there was a conflict for ports between the two - sql(that came with xampp) and my MySQL.

Comment: Not sure what system that you have, but that should be possible. I once had MySQL separate from the xampp, and all I had to do was to NOT start the xampp MySQL, then it would use the original (non-xampp) version. Other than that, if you want to run both, then the xampp mysql will need to have a different port configured (say 3307) in the xampp my.cnf file.

Comment: @PaulT. I followed what you said about letting the separate MySQL be the way it is and run the xampp, But it shows the error that 'connection for control user as defined in your configuration failed'.  An elaborated solution will be very helpful.. PS:-(Please bear with me, I'm totally novice in this field)

Comment: Sure, and I may be forgetting some other subtle details from back then. Do you mean from phpMyAdmin, or something else?  If it is phpMyAdmin, go to the phpMyAdmin directory in xampp, and check the config file for the credentials.

Comment: @PaulT. I changed the credentials in the config file. Now I get it that it merely required me to set my mysql(non-xampp version) password in that php file. Thank You so much, It was really helpful :)

Comment: No problem, glad it helped, that is good news!  :-)  ... Also, the original (non-xampp) MySQL version info should appear in the phpMyAdmin (also called PMA) home page after it loads.